# Ionic / Angular - Master detail within master detail

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, ionic-framework

Hi I'm trying to develop (using ionic, so also angular) a feature in which users can see all events, and see all attending participants. Of all these participants there is information available, so I tried making a master-detail pattern within the master-detail (so basically master-detail-detail).

Problem is, it is returning a 404 while the link is `http://localhost:8100/evenement/1/deelnemers/1` and the http function *should* return a JSON object but I couldn't test it since the page or url wasn't found.

---

**app.js**

```
// Ionic Starter App

// angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
// 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
// the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
var app = angular.module('newsApp', ['ionic']);

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    $stateProvider
  .state('list',{
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'list.html',
    controller: 'ListCtrl'
  })
  .state('detail',{
    url: '/evenement/:eventId',
    templateUrl: 'detail.html',
    controller: 'DetailCtrl'
  })
  .state('deelnemer', {
    url: '/evenement/:eventId/deelnemers/:deelnemerId',
    templateUrl: 'deelnemer.html',
    controller: 'DeelnemerCtrl'
  })
  ;

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
});

app.factory('Evenementen', function($http){
  var cachedData;

  function getData(callback){
var url = "http://localhost:8080/evenementen";

$http.get(url).success(function(data){
  cachedData = data;
  callback(data);
});
  }

  return {
list: getData,
find: function(pid, callback){
  $http.get("http://localhost:8080/evenement/"+pid).success(function(data){
    console.log("greater succes");
    console.log(data);
    callback(data);
  });
  callback(event);
}
  };
});


app.controller('ListCtrl', function($scope, $http, Evenementen){
  $scope.news = [];

  $scope.getMovieDB = function(){
Evenementen.list(function(evenementen){
  $scope.evenementen = evenementen;
});
  };

  $scope.getMovieDB();
});


app.controller('DetailCtrl', function($scope, $http, $stateParams, Evenementen){
Evenementen.find($stateParams.eventId, function(evenement){
  $scope.evenement = evenement;
  $scope.deelnemers = evenement.alleDeelnemers;
});
});

app.controller('DeelnemerCtrl', function($scope, $http, $stateParams){
  $http.get("http://localhost:8080/evenementen/"+   $stateParams.eventId+"/deelnemers/"+$stateParams.deelnemerId)
  .success(function(data){
    $scope.deelnemer = data;
  });
});




app.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
      // for form inputs)
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

      // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
      // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
      // a much nicer keyboard experience.
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });    
})
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Urls in Angular and ionic use hash, so your url should be:

```
http://localhost:8100/#/evenement/1/deelnemers/1
```

Comment: Angular (ionic also) apps are so-called "one page" apps so everything works without page reload in browser. It comes from has anchors which are html standard. It's possible to remove hash from links in Angular, but it needs also some changes at server side. If you use ionic, I assume that you want to create mobile apps also. Better leave hash then, it won't be visible for user, as urls of your app are not visiblie when they're build in cordova.